# Undefined control Sequence <argument> \@@magyar@captionfix

Tags: beamer, subcaption, subfig

When I try to compile the following code in TexMaker I get the following error

> Undefined control Sequence  @@magyar@captionfix.

Does anyone know what is the solution to that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet compilable so that it results in your given issue. As it stands now we can only guess what happened ... See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) if you need help to create a MWE for your issue ...

Comment: Is your tex system up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the tex-system using MiKTeX and the problem was solved.